Редакция предложения 2
Как отредактировать последнюю часть предложения.
Вот оригинал.
A successful sales meeting depends on both the sales person and the customer asking each other the right sort of questions.
А это дословный перевод .
Успешная торговая сделка зависит как от продавца, так и от клиента, задающих друг другу правильные вопросы.
Может написать так?
...зависит от того, задают ли продавец и клиент друг другу правильные вопросы.

В качестве варианта:
Успешная торговая сделка зависит от правильности вопросов, которые задают друг другу продавец и клиент.

Очень хороший вариант.
